# Jquery calc math not working properly in small device

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a header with a responsive img in the middle. I want to calculate 2 divs.
1 on top of img;
1 at bottom of img;
The calc is ok, except in small devices.

On the first load of the page, this is how it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jzRZ.png
If i reload the page, this is what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IbDg.png

It's happening only in screen smaller than 440px

This is the Jquery i'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        getWidthAndHeight();
    });
    $(window).load(function() {
        getWidthAndHeight();
    });
});

function getWidthAndHeight (){
    var full    = $('.header-main').outerHeight (),
        hImg    = $('.hd-m-m').height (),
        x       = hImg,
        y       = full - x,
        c1      = y * 0.3,
        c2      = (y * 0.7) + 5,
        ct      = c1 + c2 + x; //used only to confirm the result - console.log

    $('.hd-m-t').css({'height': c1});
    $('.hd-m-b').css({'height': c2});
}
```

Ps.: I have the ' +5 ' because i'm using a margin-top: -5px to cover a small blank area after the img.

And this is my HTML

```
<header id="home" class="full"><!-- home -->
    <div class="header-bg"></div><!-- background images -->

    <div class="header-main">
        <div class="hd-s"></div> <!-- div on left side -->
        <div class="hd-m">
            <div class="hd-m-t"></div> <!-- top div - needs calc -->
            <div class="hd-m-m"> <!-- middle div -->
                <img src="img/home/home-logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="hd-m-b"> <!-- bottom div - needs calc -->
                <h2>main text</h2>
                <h2>sub text</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hd-s"></div> <!-- div on right side -->
    </div><!-- transparent logo -->
</header>
```

This is the final result i'm looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/epGUL.jpg
I want to this way, because the background img will have a parallax effect and i want it to appear only trought the logo transparency.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you put your jQuery in a `$( document ).ready()` (http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)?

Comment: I update the jquery code. There is a function being called on $(document).ready and $(document).resize

Comment: Why is the `$(window).resize()` function called outside of the `$(document).ready()` function?  Do you see a change if you move it inside?

Comment: No changes. I'm still with the same problem.

Comment: I got rid of the extra margin (on the first load of the page) by changing the $(document).ready part. I already update the code above. No i only have the problem with the missing background at the bottom. Since the log is a .png img and made the call after the img is also loaded (I was reading the link you sent me and it help a bit =D )

Comment: Sorry, without the rest of the HTML (and quite possibly the CSS), it will be difficult to address the missing background at the bottom.

Comment: I've come with a solution. Maybe it's not the best way to do this, but it's working now. I did tried to put in the jsfiddle, but it was worse than it was in my website. Same code but very very different. But thanks for your help, i've learned something new =D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, after some time, i didn't found anything to solve this problem but this 'fix'.
I don't know if it's the best way or not, but here we go:

I changed the $(document).ready part, so now it execute the function after everything is loaded (including img's). This solved the extra margin at the bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        getWidthAndHeight();
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        getWidthAndHeight();
    });
});
```

Since the missing background at the bottom only happens in screen smaller than 440px, i added a if condition to the function with an extra calc. The missin background was always the same height. But i also moved the function inside the $(document).ready this is the final code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        getWidthAndHeight();
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        getWidthAndHeight();
    });

    function getWidthAndHeight (){
        var full    = $('.header-main').outerHeight (),
            hImg    = $('.hd-m-m').height (),
            x   = hImg,
            y   = full - x,
            c1  = y * 0.3,
            c2  = (y * 0.7) + 5,
            c3  = c2 + 17,
            ct  = c1 + c2 + x;

        $('.hd-m-t').css({'height': c1});
        if ($(window).width() < 440) {
            $('.hd-m-b').css({'height': c3});
        } else {
            $('.hd-m-b').css({'height': c2});
        };
    }
});
```

If anyone knows a better answer, i'll appreciate that. =D
Thanks @SableFost you gave me some good tips (even to learn extra things).

Comment: You may want to check your CSS, especially of the `.hd-m-b`.  If you are using any large padding or margins, `position:absolute;`, `float`, or `clear` (or anything else taking it out of the flow) this may be what is pushing it down.